# Unable to set a variable using EJS; Syntax Error Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm getting the following error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in [Path] while compiling ejs.

My code is as follows:

```
    <%- include ('partials/header.ejs') %>

    <h1>Results Page</h1>
    <div id="player"></div>

    <% var selectedVideo = "http://youtube.com/watch?v=video["id"]["videoId"]"; %> 

    <% output.forEach(function(video) { %>
    <li>
      <a href="http://youtube.com/watch?v=<%=video["id"]["videoId"]%>"><%=video["snippet"]["title"]%></a>
   </li>
   <% }); %> 



   <%- include ('partials/footer.ejs') %>
```

The error only occurs when I try to declare the variable selectedVideo. If I take that line out everything works. When I search this issue the solutions usually have to deal with including the partials, but those work fine if I take out the selectedVideo variable. I'm just trying to test if I can use that variable in another part of my project but this is hanging me up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: looks like nested quotes

Comment: simple as that. Thanks! that was really messing me up!